# Checking image width/height and determine what picturebox to place it in

Tags: c#, imagemagick, image-resizing, image-manipulation

Hey all I have the following pictureboxes' size's on my WPF form:

```
 Box |Width |Height
 ----|------|------
 1   |357   |272
 ----|------|------
 2   |357   |272
 ----|------|------
 3   |365   |460
 ----|------|------
 4   |365   |265
 ----|------|------
 5   |715   |455
 ----|------|------
 6   |360   |465
 ----|------|------
 7   |360   |465
 ----|------|------
 8   |360   |465
 ----|------|------
 9   |540   |290
 ----|------|------
 10  |540   |290
```

So visually it would look something like this:

```
 --------------------------
 |       |        |       |
 |   1   |    2   |       |
 |----------------|   3   |
 |                |       |
 |                |-------|
 |       5        |       |
 |                |   4   |
 |------------------------|
 |        |       |       |
 |   6    |   7   |   8   |
 |        |       |       |
 |------------------------|
 |            |           |
 |     9      |     10    |
 --------------------------
```

So what my goal is is to get the current image I am wanting to place into a box and get its width and height and from that determine the **best** box to place it in so that it will show the image:

1. Without black borders on either the left/right or top/bottom (or both).
2. Not chop off the important areas of the image (mostly the middle section moving out).

I have decided to use [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) in order to ease the pain of doing something like this from scratch. So when I determine what box I will be placing the image into then I can use the **Magick.NET** to crop it using:

**[Resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/)** 
with something like this:

```
imgStream.Crop(width, height, Gravity.Center);
```

or

```
MagickGeometry size = new MagickGeometry(width, height);
size.IgnoreAspectRatio = maintainAspectRatio;
// Adjust geometry offset to center of image (same as `-gravity Center`)
size.Y = imgStream.Height / 2 - height / 2;
size.X = imgStream.Width / 2 - width / 2;
imgStream.Crop(size);
```

So to sum up the above - I am in need of finding the best box to place the image into *before* I go and use **Magick.NET** on it.

Answer (score 0):

The best box for an image is the box with minimum value of `the difference between BoxWidth / ImageWidth and BoxHeight / ImageHeight`.

This will make sure that there will be minimum empty space when you fill the box with resized image (along with maintaining the aspect ratio). You can use the value `MIN(BoxWidth / ImageWidth, BoxHeight / ImageHeight)` to resize your image.

C# code:

```
foreach(ImageStream imgStream in Images)
{
    double MinRatioDifference = -1.0,
        Ratio = 1.0;
    Box SelectedBox = null;
    foreach(Box UnfilledBox in UnfilledBoxes)
    {
        double WidthRatio = BoxWidth / ImageWidth,
            HeightRatio = BoxHeight / ImageHeight,
            RatioDifference = WidthRatio - HeightRatio;
        if(RatioDifference < 0)
        {
            RatioDifference = -RatioDifference;
        }
        if(MinRatioDifference == -1.0 || RatioDifference < MinRatioDifference)
        {
            MinRatioDifference = RatioDifference;
            SelectedBox = UnfilledBox;
            Ratio = Math.Min(WidthRatio, HeightRatio);
        }
    }
    if(MinRatioDifference != -1.0 && SelectedBox != null)
    {
        // Fill SelectedBox with imgStream using Ratio
        UnfilledBoxes.Remove(SelectedBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, P5Coder but would you be able to put that into C# code for an example?

Comment: sorry but what should "Box" and "UnfilledBoxes" be? I have 10 image controls on the main window and looking to judge which box should be sent each image...